# How to Inherit class bu also add a new attribute in the new one

Tags: python, class, inheritance

How can I Inherit the following class but I also want to have a new attribute in the new class along with the existing one in this class;

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.gendre=gender
        print('Done by Data')
    def Name(self):
        return 'My name is '+self.name
```

this the new class in which I want to inherit data but the problem is that I can't initialize the old attribute like name,age in the instance of this class

```
class FemData(Data):
    def __init__(self,Married):
        Data.__init__(self)
        self.Married=Married
```

so i want something like this to happen

```
DataEntry=FemData('Mia',18,'female',True)
```

True is by by the way intialized to Married

Comment: If you want to pass four arguments to `FemData`, shouldn’t its constructor accept that many?

Comment: Davis that's what I'm trying to ask that why aren't the other attributes from Data class inherited in FemData

Comment: @ShoaibAtiq: **Run it**, and see what happens.

Comment: @DavisHerring if i run it with one argument it gives the error that three arguments are missing and if I run it with one argument it gives the error that FemData takes only one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here your base class constructor requires 3 parameters while your derived class requires one (excluding self). Remember that parameter needed by a base constructor need to be implicitly passed by the derived class constructor.

So your derived class constructor shall accept this parameters and then pass them on to base class constructor. Try modifying your derived class FemData as follows:

```
class FemData(Data):
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, married):
        Data.__init__(self, name, age, gender)
        self.married = married
```

Now while creating an object of type FemData, remember you have to pass all four values of name, age, gender and married.

Answer (score 0):

General advice: use `super`, and follow the rules for using `super` consistently:

1. Only  *add* arguments to the method you are overriding
2. Also accept arbitrary keyword arguments so that whatever arguments
     you don't recognize can be passed up the chain
3. Do *not* pass on arguments that you added to the method; no upstream
    call will know what to do with them.
4. Use keyword arguments when calling your function.

Putting these into practice,

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, **kwargs):
        # name, age, and gender are "handled" here, so
        # don't pass them on
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gendre = gender

    def Name(self):
        return 'My name is '+self.name


class FemData(Data):
   def __init__(self, married, **kwargs):
       # married is "handled" here, so don't pass them on
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.married = married

# In this example, the MRO for FemData is [FemData, Data, object].
# FemData.__init__ handles married and passes on name, age, and gender
# Data.__init__ handles name, age, and gender and passes on nothing
# object.__init__ receives no arguments, and so does not raise an exception.
DataEntry = FemData(name='Mia', age=18, gender='female', married=True)
```

Although `FemData` seems to imply that gender should be female, so you hard-code that in the call to `super().__init__`, ignoring/overriding any explicit argument.

```
class FemData(Data):
   def __init__(self, married, **kwargs):
       kwargs['gender'] = 'female'
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.married = married


DataEntry = FemData(name='Mia', age=18, married=True)
```